# How to soften when doing morpher animation

Tags: ios, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

When I use a morph animation for a model, the model automatically turns into a hard edge. How should we avoid such changes?

```
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "morpher.weights[0]")
animation.fromValue = 0.0
animation.toValue = 1.0
animation.autoreverses = true
animation.repeatCount = MAXFLOAT
animation.duration = 0.25
face.addAnimation(animation, forKey: nil)
```

[here is the animation](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YuO_K52x0Dv_5unDryMH4mGbCVWsJ3qi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **There could be three potential problems causing your model to show hard edges at animation**:

- insufficient number of polygons in 3D models (low-poly models)
- source and target models have different number of polygons
- models have lamina faces, [non-manifold geo](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya-lt/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/MayaLT/files/Mesh--Cleanup-htm.html), or non-planar faces

***Supposedly, you may have all the listed problems at once or just one of them.***